# Unable to remove nvidia and cuda drivers

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

## Question

Regardless of how I got here, I really just want to completely remove nvidia and cuda drivers and reeinstall them. But, no matter what I do, I can't get rid of them.

## Background

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04 and I was using a working nvidia-535 driver and successfully installed cuda 11-8 (using [instructions here](https://gist.github.com/MihailCosmin/affa6b1b71b43787e9228c25fe15aeba)).

Now, for some (to me) unknown reason (possibly some update) cuda stopped working (i.e. gpu not utilized in e.g. stable diffusion) and `nvidia-smi` returned

```
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
NVML library version: 535.161
```

Hence wanted to try and remove everything cuda and nvidia related and start over, since I know it was working fine before.

## I have tried

- `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*` returns

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'nvidia-driver-550-server' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-firmware-535-535.154.05' for glob 'nvidia*'
Note, selecting 'nvidia-docker2' for glob 'nvidia*'

... [ca. 300 similar rows] ...

Package 'nvidia-egl-wayland-common' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'nvidia-settings' instead of 'nvidia-settings-binary'
Package 'nvidia-390' is not installed, so not removed
Note, selecting 'libnvtt-bin' instead of 'nvidia-texture-tools'
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-current-updates' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-libopencl1' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia' is not installed, so not removed

... [ca. 500 similar rows] ...

Package 'nvidia-container-toolkit-base' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-firmware-545-545.29.02' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nvidia-firmware-550-550.40.07' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-535 : Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-dkms-535 (>= 535.129.03)
                    Depends: nvidia-driver-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed or
                             nvidia-kernel-open-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-utils-535 (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-modprobe (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: nvidia-settings (>= 535.129.03) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

- As suggested I tried:
  `sudo apt --fix-broken install` which returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libsbc1 nvidia-firmware-535-535.146.02 nvidia-firmware-535-535.161.07
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nvidia-kernel-common-535
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 45,1 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 256847 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-kernel-common-535 (535.161.07-0ubuntu1) over (535.154.05-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack)
:
 trying to overwrite '/lib/firmware/nvidia/535.161.07/gsp_ga10x.bin', which is also in package nvidia-firmware-535-535.1
61.07 535.161.07-0ubuntu0.22.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

- `sudo apt autoremove` gives:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.161.07-0ubuntu1) but 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

- `sudo apt remove --purge "*cuda*"` returns:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libcuda-10.2-1' for glob '*cuda*'
Note, selecting 'libcudart.so.12' for glob '*cuda*'

... [ ca. 800 rows ] ...

Package 'libcudss0-cuda-12' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libcudss0-dev-cuda-12' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libcudss0-static-cuda-12' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcublas-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcufft-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                          cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                          cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcufile-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcurand-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcusolver-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcusparse-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libnpp-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                        cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
               Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                        cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
               Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libnvjpeg-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.161.07-0ubuntu1) but 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

- As described in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431461/how-to-remove-cuda-completely-from-ubuntu), I tried to locate the uninstaller:
  `sudo /usr/local/cuda-11.4/bin/cuda-uninstaller` but there is no cuda or nvidia directory under `/usr/local/`.
- I checked `/etc/apt/sources.list`, there is no instance of 'nvidia' or 'cuda', (i.e. `cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep nvidia` returns nothing.
- Following instructions in an additional [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431461/how-to-remove-cuda-completely-from-ubuntu), `sudo apt-get --purge remove "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*"` returned:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cublasmp-cuda-11' for glob '*cublas*'
Note, selecting 'cublasmp-cuda-12' for glob '*cublas*'

... [ >100 similar rows ] ...

Package 'libcublas-dev-12-4' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nsight-compute-2024.1.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nsight-systems-2023.4.4' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcufft-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                          cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                          cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                 Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcufile-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcurand-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcusolver-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libcusparse-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                             cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                    Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libnpp-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                        cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
               Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                        cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
               Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 libnvjpeg-11-8 : Depends: cuda-toolkit-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-config-common but it is not going to be installed or
                           cuda-cudart-11-2 but it is not installable
                  Depends: cuda-toolkit-11-8-config-common but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.161.07-0ubuntu1) but 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

*In conclusion, no matter what I try to remove, it won't let me because of unmet dependencies. I have tried starting to remove the last packages above (e.g. libcufft-11-8) one by one, but I just get a very similar output again listing other related packages.*

Also,
`sudo apt update` returns:

```
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                                                              
Hit:3 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease                                                      
Hit:4 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease                                                    
Hit:5 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                          
Hit:6 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64  InRelease                            
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]                                              
Hit:8 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu jammy InRelease                            
Hit:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [848 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe i386 Packages [597 kB]
Get:12 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [162 kB]
Fetched 1 716 kB in 2s (1 033 kB/s)                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
29 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
W: https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
```

and `sudo apt upgrade` doesn't work:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-dkms-535 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-535 (= 535.161.07-0ubuntu1) but 535.154.05-0ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

## System details

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Kernel: 6.5.0-21-generic

Comment: You should not be confused. At the beginning of your long post you said you were using 24.04, which is a development version and therefore off topic. This led to the closure. At the very end you say 22.04, so maybe the first version you mentioned was a typo? It's unsurprising that few would read so long a post when it was clearly off topic from what you wrote under "background". If it was a typo, fix it and the question could get reopened.

Comment: All you have to do in order to remove what you want to remove is run `sudo apt purge cuda-drivers-535 nvidia*` or possibly `sudo apt purge nvidia* cuda-drivers-535 libcufft-11-8 libcufile-11-8 libcurand-11-8 libcusolver-11-8 libcusparse-11-8 libnpp-11-8 libnvjpeg-11-8` or  if that doesn't work then, `sudo apt purge  "nvidia*" "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*" libcufft-11-8 libcufile-11-8 libcurand-11-8 libcusolver-11-8 libcusparse-11-8 libnpp-11-8 libnvjpeg-11-8`

Comment: or `sudo apt purge "nvidia*" "*cublas*" "cuda*" "nsight*" libcufft-11-8 libcufile-11-8 libcurand-11-8 libcusolver-11-8 libcusparse-11-8 libnpp-11-8 libnvjpeg-11-8 nvidia-dkms-535`

Comment: It seems OP is using 22.04

Comment: The graphics-drivers and/or cuda ppas are probably contributing to this problem.

Comment: Ah, yes, 24 was a typo, I am indeed on 22.04; my bad. What makes it long are really just the outputs (alot of which you only need to read the last rows, but it's included for completeness). The point is that I cannot do any remove or purges etc, as can be seen by what I have tried. However, for me, setting the driver to Nouveau in "Software and Updates" and restarting made it possible to remove and purge, i.e. it's solved now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After simply manually setting the driver to Nouveau in "Software and Updates" and rebooting, `sudo apt remove --purge nvidia*`, `sudo apt remove --purge "*cuda*"`, etc (as listed in my question and suggested by Siarhei) worked as expected and gave no errors.

Simple, I know, but previously (and on other systems) I have been able to do this without manually activating the Nouveau drivers and restarting, so I guess it just didn't occur to me at the time.

(Thank you all for reopening and for your answers. Also, apologies for the typo.)

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue when running `sudo apt --fix-broken install`

Try running something like this to fix it

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-535_535.161.07-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

Then reboot the machine.

Answer (score 0):

Step by step:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*

sudo apt remove nvidia-*

sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cuda*

sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo rm -rf /usr/local/cuda*
```

If the commands above won't help, boot via Grab menu and try them again.

P.S. Worked for me on multiple Ubuntu versions